# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""

Tags: python, pip

I'm new to Python and I was trying to use the numpy and matplotlib library. I saw in some tutorials that I had to use the cmd window and pip to install said libraries. However whenever I write  `>pip install numpy` in the cmd window, the message `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "direction of python"` shows. I installed Python 3.9.6 from the official website and I have already the pip installed (whenever I write  python `-m pip install -U pip` I say I have the requierement already satisfied). Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have too some libs that conflict with one one another version.

To avoid such situation, you must use virtualenv, it's a best practice. and then install your package with pip

learn more about venv in python

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
```

after you resolve and active virtualenv, install package with pip, and it not works yet, try with pip3. if you dont have pip3, install it and then try again